# service to 301 redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain, http-status-code-301

I'm about to write this code (using tomcat so I don't think there's an easy .htaccess solution), but figured I would see if there's already a service that does this for me.  I need mydomain.com/* to be redirected to www.mydomain.com/*.  So the easiest thing to do, if it exists, is to point the dns record for mydomain.com to a service which just does a 301 redirect to www.mydomain.com **with the same path and parameters**.

Any such service exist?

Comment: no, just edited the question to reflect that I'm using tomcat, so I don't think there's an easy declarative way to do this.  The code might take me slightly longer than writing this question and reading the answers, but I'm curious anyway if there's a service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same and found

http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect.

Not sure I would want to use as it looks like a bit of a hobby sideline and could, I guess be turned off at anytime, especially if their bandwidth bills started to go up

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, but I went with these guys: http://www.arecord.net